# How to pivot a data-ng-repeat data in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a data like below

```
Supplier A
ProductID 1001
Price 2.3
Supplier A
Product ID 2001
Price 4.3
Supplier A
Product ID 3001
Price 4.6
Supplier B
ProductID 1001
Price 5.3
Supplier B
Product ID 2001
Price 5.0
Supplier B
Product ID 3001
Price 5.6
```

I use the below code to display the data as it is

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="Emp in EmpAddressList">
    <td>{{Emp.rackPrice.SupplierName}}</td>
    <td>{{Emp.rackPrice.ProductID}}</td>
    <td>{{Emp.rackPrice.Price}}</td>                
</tr>
```

but i want to display the data in a pivoted format

```
Supplier     1001    2001    3001
A            2.3     4.3     4.6 
B            5.0     5.2     5.6
```

Can some one help me to modify this code

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create an array for the headings using the product ID's and an object for the pivot data

Repeating rows for suppliers from pivotData and then repeating the  headings gives you 2 properties to get the price for that column and row.

If you need a more robust sortable table...map the pivotData object to arrays instead

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  var
    pivotData = $scope.pivotData = {},
    headings = $scope.headings = [];


  data.forEach(o => {
    if (!headings.includes(o.ProductID)) {
      headings.push(o.ProductID)
    }
    pivotData[o.Supplier] = pivotData[o.Supplier] || {};
    pivotData[o.Supplier][o.ProductID] = o.Price
  });

  headings.sort((a, b) => a - b);  

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Supplier</th>
      <th ng-repeat="h in headings">{{h}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="(supp, obj) in pivotData">
      <th>{{supp}}</th>
      <td ng-repeat="h in headings">{{obj[h]}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <h4>PivotData</h4>
  <pre>{{pivotData|json}}</pre>
</div>




<script>
  var data = [{
    "Supplier": "A",
    "ProductID": "1001",
    "Price": "2.3"
  }, {
    "Supplier": "A",
    "ProductID": "2001",
    "Price": "4.3"
  }, {
    "Supplier": "A",
    "ProductID": "3001",
    "Price": "4.6"
  }, {
    "Supplier": "B",
    "ProductID": "1001",
    "Price": "5.3"
  }, {
    "Supplier": "B",
    "ProductID": "2001",
    "Price": "5.0"
  }, {
    "Supplier": "B",
    "ProductID": "3001",
    "Price": "5.6"
  }]
</script>
```